# How to handle different children with XStream?

Tags: java, xml, xstream

This is the scenario:

```
<family>
    <person>name</person>
    <person>
        <address> street </adress>
        <address> street </address>
    </person>
</family>
```

The person value can be a list of addresses or just the person name.
I think the solution is to use a converter but how do you do that?

1. Check what input you retrieve?
2. Tell the converter to just continue using the defaults for class 3?

Example class : (do note that this is for illustration)

```
public class Person {

    private String name;

    private List<Address> address;
}

public class Address {
    private String street;    
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by a list of values? List<class3>? Can you post the definition of class2 please?

Comment: Improved my question :-)

Comment: In this case why not make name an attribute? Would that make sense in your real situation?

Comment: Unfortunaly not, this person address example is an illustration example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need to use a converter. Here is the converter for your example:

```
public class PersonConverter implements Converter {

    public void marshal(Object value, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
        Person person = (Person) value;
        if(person.name != null){
            writer.setValue(person.name);
        } else if(person.address != null){
            for (Address address : person.address){
                writer.startNode("address");
                writer.setValue(address.street);
                writer.endNode();
            }
        }


    }

    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.name = reader.getValue();
        if(person.name.trim().length()==0){
            person.name = null;
        }
        List<Address> addresses = getAddress(reader, new ArrayList<Address>());
        person.address = addresses;
        if(person.address.size() == 0){
            person.address = null;
        }
        return person;
    }

    private List<Address> getAddress(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, List<Address> addresses){
        if (!reader.hasMoreChildren()){
            return addresses;
        }
        reader.moveDown();
        if(reader.getNodeName().equals("address")){
            addresses.add(new Address(reader.getValue()));
            reader.moveUp();
            getAddress(reader, addresses);
        }
        return addresses;
    }

    public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {
        return clazz.equals(Person.class);
    }
}
```

Here is the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
    persons.add(new Person("John"));

    List<Address> adds = new ArrayList<Address>();
    adds.add(new Address("123 street"));
    adds.add(new Address("456 street"));

    persons.add(new Person(adds));

    Family family = new Family(persons);


    XStream stream = new XStream();     
    stream.registerConverter(new PersonConverter());
    stream.processAnnotations(new Class[]{Family.class});

    String xml = stream.toXML(family);
    System.out.println(xml);

    Family testFam = (Family) stream.fromXML(xml);
    System.out.println("family.equals(testFam) => "+family.equals(testFam));

}
```

If you implement the equals method for the `Family`, `Person`, and `Address` classes it should print that they are equal at the end of the method when ran. Also worth noting is that I used some Annotations on the `Family`. I used `@XStreamAlias("family")` on the Class itself, and then on the collection of `Person` objects I used `@XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName="person")`.

And here is my ouput when I run the main method supplied:

```
<family>
  <person>John</person>
  <person>
    <address>123 street</address>
    <address>456 street</address>
  </person>
</family>
family.equals(testFam) => true
```